# how to insert many items from a file txt to a database in one step

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys I'm about to create a quiz as a school project
so the web application allow users to pass a quiz 
the problem is I've too many questions to add and each question has a correct answer and 3 choices so it's way too difficult to add all this stuff in the database 
so I'm wondered if I could do it automatically 
this is a question table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
    `Id_Qst` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'identifiant',
    `choice1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `choice2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    `choice3` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    `correctanswer1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `correctanswer2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    `qst1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `qst2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lvl` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Image` blob NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id_QstS`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

composed questions are included in my quiz so I chose to add qst1 and qst2
Thank you !

Comment: Please show a sample of your file. The will show us how to match column names to the data in your file.

Comment: Just write the proper SQL insert statement?

Comment: step back, take a deep breath, and make it more clear

Comment: This not a clear problem description; please rephrase. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask